# SpringBootServletInitializer causes loader constraint violation with slf4j

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, wso2-identity-server

I have Spring Boot application which is deployed on WSO2 IS. For the upgrade reasons, I had to upgrade some dependencies and I went from Spring Boot 1.5.10 to 2.2.2. I have to do some adjustments in the code, but one thing is causing below problem:

> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/wso2/carbon/webapp/mgt/loader/CarbonWebappClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature

So, in this app I have class which is initializing servlet using SpringBootServletInitializer:

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(App.class);
    }
```

I observed that when I remove extension of SpringBootServletInitializer, then I don't get any errors. I can't see what can cause such behavior.

Comment: If you remove `SpringBootServletInitializer` you won't get any errors because youra pplication doesn't do anything anymore. Looks like a classloading issue and feels like SLF4J is loaded with a different classloader as well. Not sure how to influence classloading for WSO2 you might need to dig into the manuals for that.

Comment: Why have you deployed a Spring boot application inside the WSO2 Identity Server? It is not usually recommended to add any custom web apps inside the Identity Server.

Comment: I don't know reason why it was done like this, but in IS 5.8 it works fine. Currently we are preparing to move to 5.11 and during that, I encounter problems.

Comment: If you can explain the usage of this application, it would be easy to provide a good resolution for the issue. Probably reaching out the WSO2 Identity Server slack channel would be the best option. Find the invitation link from here https://wso2.com/community/slack/